# Flag a discussion in chat as no longer needed

Tags: support, flags, chat

Comments can be flagged as being no longer needed (NLN). If they are moved to chat, they are converted to messages in chat, which can no longer be flagged as NLN. The whole chat can also not be flagged as NLN. The only options are to flag each individual message as "spam, inappropriate or offensive" or "for moderator".

Is there no need to clean up discussions in chat? Is it enough to just flag the comment

> Let us continue this discussion in chat.

for NLN and let the chat float around with no link to it any more? Or is it appropriate to flag the chat for moderator intervention with "NLN" as the message?

Comment: Why do you need the chat messages removed?

Comment: The same reason as for comments - NLN.

Comment: On the main site, comments are second class citizens. They could detract from the main content - questions and answers. Hence why they can be removed when no longer needed. Why do you say that *chat messages* would need to be removed? What is the driving reason to have them gone?

Comment: The driving reason might be to not pollute the system anymore. The given tools give me the impression, that it is OK to have chats floating around forever, but I just don't know it for sure. So a statement like "SO does not care about NLN chats" would give me the guidance/clarification I am looking for.

Comment: "The system" isn't a thing that can meaningfully be polluted. For example, the server has databases that continue to store "deleted" questions - after all, undeletion is possible. What gets polluted is *the page output*. Long comment chains on a Q&A are noise that move the Q and the As further apart, and otherwise distract the reader, while also making the site look more like the discussion forum that it isn't.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Moderators do not clean up chat messages in the way that we clean up comments. Comments are inlined directly on the page with the questions and answers, and thus noisy comment threads crowd out and distract from useful content. Chat is never inlined on the Q&A page, so it doesn't matter. The entire design of chat is that it's a place where people can talk freely, without worrying about being "noisy". It is a waste of time to clean up chat transcripts. That's why there is no "no longer needed" flag for individual chat messages. Individual chat messages should generally only be flagged when they contain something that [shocks the conscience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shocks_the_conscience) (*i.e.*, is rude, offensive, etc.) and needs to be immediately removed.

If, when prompted, you moved a conversation from the comments into chat, and that *entire* chat conversation is irrelevant/uninteresting/obsolete, then you can flag the comment containing the link to the chat room as "no longer needed" (or, preferably, with a custom flag where you explain the uselessness of the linked chat and ask that it be deleted and the comment linking it removed).